# how to fetch data from basecamp classic api in json format

Tags: php, json, basecamp

The data from  BASECAMP  api is in xml format so for some projects, people JSON format is working well.

But how to resolve this problem from basecamp classic api.

1. I have googled   and find that basecamp api is in xml format but i want data in json format .
2. I am  just trying to fetch data in JSON format , but  error shown in browser:
    You may have typed the URL incorrectly
3. In there api they have mentioned to fetch GET /GET /categories/#{id}.xml .

Here is my Code :

```
 $Comments=$client->fetch('https://basecamp.com/*****/api/v1/categories.json');
```

Comment: If they don’t offer JSON, then you could fetch the XML and convert it to JSON yourself for your further processing … maybe even extend their client object by a method that does exactly that.

Comment: then error shown Warning: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be string. my code                                                     $xml = simplexml_load_file($Comments) or die("error")

Comment: And what _is_ the return value of the `fetch` method …?

Comment: when print_r$Comments it shows You may have typed the URL incorrectly. though i have cross this url with project and people its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two versions of Basecamp, each with their own API.  For Basecamp Classic, your account will look like https://subdomain.basecamphq.com, while for the new Basecamp, your url will be https://basecamp.com/1234567

The Basecamp Classic API returns XML, and the [docs are here](https://github.com/basecamp/basecamp-classic-api).  The new Basecamp API returns JSON, and the [docs are here](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api).

To get all of the categories from the Classic API, you'll want to use

`https://#{subdomain}.basecamphq.com/projects/#{project_id}/categories.xml`

Comment: there is another bug im facing error is:                                   Warning: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 2 to be a class name derived. and my code  $xml = simplexml_load_file($result,true); so please tell where im  wrong.

Comment: how to fetch comments and plaese help me to diffrentiate b/w comments and milstone and todoitems

Comment: Check https://github.com/basecamp/basecamp-classic-api/blob/master/sections/comments.md for grabbing the comments (and we run through how to distinguish comments on milestones from comments on todo items, posts or calendar events there too )